# data.table fill missing values from other rows by group

Tags: r, data.table, row, na

```
# have
> aDT <- data.table(colA = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), colB = c(4,NA,NA,1,4,3,NA,NA,4,NA,2,NA))
> aDT
    colA colB
 1:    1    4
 2:    1   NA
 3:    1   NA
 4:    1    1
 5:    2    4
 6:    2    3
 7:    2   NA
 8:    2   NA
 9:    3    4
10:    3   NA
11:    3    2
12:    3   NA
# want
> bDT <- data.table(colA = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), colB = c(4,1,1,1,4,3,3,3,4,2,2,2))
> bDT
    colA colB
 1:    1    4
 2:    1    1
 3:    1    1
 4:    1    1
 5:    2    4
 6:    2    3
 7:    2    3
 8:    2    3
 9:    3    4
10:    3    2
11:    3    2
12:    3    2
```

Would like to fill missing values according to the algorithm below:
within each group ('colA'),

1. use the value from one row below, if it's still NA, keeps going until the last row within that group
2. if all NAs in rows below, look at rows above (go up 1 row at a time)
3. if all NAs, then NA

Since the dataset is quite large, algorithmic efficiency is part of consideration. Not sure if there's any package for this type of operation already. How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `data.table` and `zoo`:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

# Last observation carried forward from last row of group
dt <- dt[, colB := na.locf0(colB, fromLast = TRUE), by = colA]

# Last observation carried forward for first row of group
dt[, colB := na.locf(colB), by = colA][]
```

Or in a single chain:

```
dt[, colB := na.locf0(colB, fromLast = TRUE), by = colA][
   , colB := na.locf(colB), by = colA][]
```

Both return:

```
    colA colB
 1:    1    4
 2:    1    1
 3:    1    1
 4:    1    1
 5:    2    4
 6:    2    3
 7:    2    3
 8:    2    3
 9:    3    4
10:    3    2
11:    3    2
12:    3    2
```

Data:

```
text <- "colA colB
    1    4
    1   NA
    1   NA
    1    1
    2    4
    2    3
    2   NA
    2   NA
    3    4
    3   NA
    3    2
    3   NA"

dt <- fread(input = text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way using `tidyverse` and `zoo::na.locf`:

```
library(tidyverse);
library(zoo);
df %>%
    group_by(colA) %>%
    arrange(colA) %>%
    mutate(colB = na.locf(colB, na.rm = F, fromLast = TRUE)) %>%
    mutate(colB = na.locf(colB, na.rm = F));
## A tibble: 12 x 2
## Groups:   colA [3]
#    colA  colB
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  1.00  4.00
# 2  1.00  1.00
# 3  1.00  1.00
# 4  1.00  1.00
# 5  2.00  4.00
# 6  2.00  3.00
# 7  2.00  3.00
# 8  2.00  3.00
# 9  3.00  4.00
#10  3.00  2.00
#11  3.00  2.00
#12  3.00  2.00
```

Or the `data.table` way:

```
library(data.table);
dt[, .(na.locf(na.locf(colB, na.rm = F, fromLast = T), na.rm = F)), by = .(colA)];
#    colA V1
# 1:    1  4
# 2:    1  1
# 3:    1  1
# 4:    1  1
# 5:    2  4
# 6:    2  3
# 7:    2  3
# 8:    2  3
# 9:    3  4
#10:    3  2
#11:    3  2
#12:    3  2
```

The key in both cases is to apply `na.locf` twice: First to replace `NA`s from the bottom, then replace the remaining `NA`s from the top.

---

### Sample data

```
# As data.frame
df <- data.frame(colA = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), colB = c(4,NA,NA,1,4,3,NA,NA,4,NA,2,NA));
# As data.table
dt <- data.table(colA = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), colB = c(4,NA,NA,1,4,3,NA,NA,4,NA,2,NA));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

aDT%>%group_by(colA)%>%fill(colB,.direction="up")%>%fill(colB)
# A tibble: 12 x 2
# Groups:   colA [3]
    colA  colB
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     4
 2     1     1
 3     1     1
 4     1     1
 5     2     4
 6     2     3
 7     2     3
 8     2     3
 9     3     4
10     3     2
11     3     2
12     3     2
```